# When would you use "hot mud" or setting joint compound for leveling concrete?

Tags: concrete, self-leveling-concrete, drywall-mud

To my surprise (or ignorance) the bag of 'hot mud' I bought specifically says it can be used for :

> *leveling interior above grade concrete*

When would this be an appropriate choice, and does it have any advantages to just using more concrete or cement-based self leveling compound?

I'm skeptical about this because:

- There's no way this type of "plaster" type material seems like it could be nearly as hard / strong as concrete. Just based on my experience with both materials. (Though maybe hard enough for a subfloor?)
- Secondly its more expensive at about 61 cents/lb vs 54 cents/lb for self-leveling compound, which is itself pricey for cement-type products; regular premixed concrete or mortar would be only ~10% of that.
- I don't see the mud as being particularly easier to work with. There's mix, mess, cleanup to deal with regardless.

So given those downsides I'm curious why they recommend it for this use. Are there specific applications or situations where it's better? Maybe just the quick setting time?

[image]

[image]

Comment: My gut feel is that it's appropriate for a teensy tiny bit of filling (cracks, divots, etc), but I wouldn't want to try to level an entire floor with it. I don't know if I want to blame or congratulate the manufacturer for playing at the edge of reality.

Comment: Above grade may indicate not on the floor. I would patch concrete walls with this but not a floor. It isn’t hard enough for foot traffic

Comment: Agree with @kris that you'd never want to walk on setting compound. I was thinking about filling prior to putting something else on top of it.

Comment: @Kris that makes sense although I wouldn't have thought "leveling" would refer to a wall...